# How do I fix assembly at&t segmentation error from adding two numbers

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu

```
.globl _start
_start:

mov $3,%ah     
mov $5,%al

add %ah,%al

movl $0,%ebx
int 0x80
```

I assemble and link like this without errors:

```
as file.s -o file.o
ld file.o -o file
```

but if I run it ./file then it gives me segmentation error.

I've searched it up but I dont get where I did wrong (newbie here..?)
please help....

Comment: What do you expect the `int 0x80` to do?

Comment: You need to set `eax` to `1` before the `int 0x80` otherwise it's not going to be an exit system call.

Comment: I forgot to type the code but I do have the exit call before int 0x80 in actual code

Comment: No, you don't.  Run `strace ./file` and/or single-step it with GDB.  `int $0x80` needs a call number in EAX.  You don't have `mov $__NR_exit, %eax` before the int $0x80. (It also has to be after the instructions that mess with the the low 2 bytes of EAX, AL and AH.)  In future, always copy/paste your actual code, and use a code-formatting block (triple backticks).

Comment: @SoHungry Please post your actual code then.  It is very difficult to diagnose problems with code that you have not posted or reproduced incorrectly or incompletely.  [Edit] your question and add your actual code.